# Adding a comment to a partition column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the following hive table, where eventdate is the partition column:

```
hive> describe item_pages;
siteid                  int                     the site identifier for the host domain
externalsessionid       string                  the instrumented sessionid
item_pages              array<string>           an array of all distinct page IDs
eventdate               string                  None                

# Partition Information      
# col_name              data_type               comment             

eventdate               string                  None
```

Is there a way that I can add a comment to the table metadata for the partition column? I get the following response when treating the eventdate partition column as a regular column:

```
hive> ALTER TABLE da_itempages CHANGE eventdate eventdate string COMMENT 'the PST calendar date of the item page views in YYYY-MM-DD format'
Column 'eventdate' does not exists
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

(the example command is the exact same command the successfully inserted comments into the columns that have columns per the describe statement.)

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue? I am going thru the same issue recently

Comment: Don't remember, but I assume I didn't.

Comment: There is no solution to this problem. I think someone has to raise the ticket with hive team regarding this.

Comment: Accoding to [Hive LanguageManual DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RenamePartition): Partitions can be added, renamed, exchanged (moved), dropped, or (un)archived by using the PARTITION clause in an ALTER TABLE statement. There is no comment options :(